# How to find number of characters in dynamic array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am very much a beginner at C++, and I've been trying for the past 6 hours to try to figure out how to get the number of characters in a dynamic array.
This is the code I have:

```
using namespace std;

int array_size;
typedef char* charPtr;
charPtr a = new char[array_size];
char *p=a;

int len(char p[]) {
int count = 0;
while (*p != '\0'); {
    count++;
    p++;
    return count;
    }
}

int main() {

    cout << "Type a phrase" << endl;
    cin >> array_size;
    cout << "Your phrase was " << len(p) << " characters long." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Reading a phrase instead of a number would be a good idea.

Comment: Especially for beginners I would recommend to stay away from C-style constructs and use things like `std::string` or `std::vector`. Many books follow the traditional approach and introduce C (maybe with classes), and then higher-level C++ constructs which is IMHO not the right way. I would recommend to try "A Tour of C++" (https://isocpp.org/tour).

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the semicolon (`;`) after the temination condition of your while loop. `;` is the end of an statement, after that a new statment beginns. Apart from this your `return` statement would be inside the `while` loop. Remove it outside the loop. Adapt your code like this:

```
int len(char p[]) {
    int count = 0;
    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        count++;
        p++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Further you have to read a string from input into your dynamicly allocated array of `char`:

```
int main() {

    int array_size = 100;
    char *p=new char[array_size];      // allocate memory

    cout << "Type a phrase" << endl;
    cin >> p;                          // read string into allocated memory

    cout << "Your phrase was " << len(p) << " characters long." << endl;

    delete p;                          // free memory
    return 0; 
}
```

The function `strlen` gives you the length of a `\0`-terminated string.

```
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    int array_size = 100;
    char *p=new char[array_size];     // allocate memory

    cout << "Type a phrase" << endl;
    cin >> p;                         // read string into allocated memory

    cout << "Your phrase was " << strlen(p) << " characters long." << endl;

    delete p;                         // free memory
    return 0; 
}
```

**But I recommend to use `std::string`:**

```
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string str;
    cout << "Type a phrase" << endl;
    cin >> str;

    cout << "Your phrase was " << str.size() << " characters long." << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

`std::string` represents a sequences of characters with dynamic length.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was under the impression that you could have the user choose the size of the array via cin, but I can see now that I was going about it incorrectly anyway.
It took me a few more hours, but I finally understand the concepts now.
Thanks again for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

**Getting the size of dynamically allocated array**

A dynamically allocated array does not have any information about its size that is available in a standards compliant way.

We are able to compute the length of C style strings since there is sentinel element, `'\0'`, to mark the end of the string. There are no such elements for other types.

Even then, you cannot compute the size of an array of characters allocated using heap memory like you have.

**Problems with posted code**

1. You have the following lines outside all functions.

   ```
   int array_size;
   typedef char* charPtr;
   charPtr a = new char[array_size];
   char *p=a;
   ```

   They are executed before anything in `main` gets executed. When these lines are executed, `array_size` gets initialized to `0`. Then you allocate memory for `charPtr` using `0` as the value of `array_size`.
2. Function `len` has an error due to a typo, which could lead to either (a) a hanging program or an incorrect return value.

   ```
   int len(char p[])
   {
      int count = 0;

      while (*p != '\0');
                  //   ^^^ The semicolon is a problem
      {
         count++;
         p++;
         return count;
      }
   }
   ```

   If `*p` is not equal to `'\0'`, the program will never get out of the `while` statement. It will hange.

   If `*p` is equal to `'\0'`, the program will get out of the `while` statement but it will still execute the the lines after that. As a consequence, you will end up returning `1` as the length where `0` is the right answer.
3. In `main`, you have:

   ```
   cout << "Type a phrase" << endl;
   cin >> array_size;
   ```

   When the user sees the output, they will try to enter a phrase. However, `array_size` is an `int`. There is a mismatch between the prompt to the user and the line to read the data.

   You could change it them to:

   ```
   cout << "Type array size" << endl;
   cin >> array_size;
   cout << "Type a phrase" << endl;
   ```

   That is one step better but that still does not change the fact that memory for `a` was allocated using a size of `0`.
4. Using uninitialized memory

   You are calling `len(p)` in the `cout` line but the elements of `p` have not been initialized.

It's not clear from your post what the program is supposed to do. I am guessing that you want to read a phrase from `stdin` and write it out to `stdout`. You can use the following simplified version for that.

```
int main() 
{
   std::string phrase;
   cout << "Type a phrase" << endl;

   // Get the entire line as a phrase.
   std::getline(std::cin, phrase);

   cout << "Your phrase is " << phrase << endl;
   cout << "It is " << phrase.size() << " characters long." << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. OP has the code to get the length (which may contain some errors). They have some other problems which they haven't specified (I can see one unrelated error which would result in failure to compile.)

Answer (score 0):

First problem: you cannot use array_size till it has been initialized.

> `char* a = new char [array_size]`

since array_size has not been initialized and has garbage data in it, you have no idea how big that array is going to be.

that's why first you have to initialize `array_size`, and only after allocate your `char array`.

like

```
int array_size = 0 //no reason to have this variable as global, but that's up to you 
char *a = nullptr; //same

int main()
{
    cin >> array_size;

    if (array_size <= 0) //make sure the input is valid and not negative
         return 0;       

    a = new char[array_size];

    //now you can work on your newly allocated array of characters

    //the number of characters the array has equals to the array_size variable.

    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

your len function checks for a '\0' character, but again, you have not initialized that char array either, so it contains garbage data. therefore sometimes you may get a result of len 5, 10, 502043, anything can happen really (undefined behavior).